# Regex capture group definition in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am having some issues with the following python. I am trying to match strings that are inside single quotes, but only capture the contents, that is, drop the single quotes themselves.

```
In [144]: tststr = "'hello'"

In [145]: res = re.search(r"'(.*)'", tststr)

In [146]: res.group()
Out[146]: "'hello'"
```

I would expect the output to only contain "hello" without the single quotes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the group index number of the group  which actually stores the captured characters.  Without the index number, `res.group()` will print all the matched characters in your case, it was `'hello'` .

```
res.group(1)
```

Ex:

```
>>> tststr = "'hello'"
>>> res = re.search(r"'(.*)'", tststr)
>>> res.group(1)
'hello'
```